# Key chain items not auto deleted when device passcode is removed

Tags: ios, swift, security, storage, keychain

While storing keychain items , we are specifying kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly for kSecAttrAccessible
by this
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessiblewhenpasscodesetthisdeviceonly
the items have to be auto deleted when passcode is removed. but thats not happening , Anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: As for security, the items are no longer available to use. You should get an OSStatus of `-25293` or `errSecAuthFailed` if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've seen that issue before, yet I'd be careful to interpret Apple's doc here in a way that this happens immediately.

This might happen at a later time after a restart, or some other event.